# Reading APK Expansion Files with MonoDroid

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, monogame

I am currently working on porting an XNA Windows Phone 7 game to Android using MonoGame and MonoDroid. I ported the game, added in multiple resolution support and ended up with an APK that is 130 MB. I quickly discovered that Google Play does not support APK files larger than 50 MB, and would have to use APK Expansion Files.

So I read through Google Documentation about Expansion Files. Then I zipped up all my game's textures without any compression setting, renamed the zip file to:

```
main.1.com.baller.fivesome.obb
```

I then placed the obb file into the appropriate place:
http://www.ballerindustries.com/images/path.png

My code crashing while trying to open up the OBB file:

```
using(ZipFile zif = new ZipFile(sourcePath))
```

Here's the contents of sourcePath:
http://www.ballerindustries.com/images/sourcePath.png

It results in a Java.IO.FileNotFoundException

So I guess my questions are:
1. Am I missing something obvious?
2. Have I placed the OBB into the right location?
3. Have I built the OBB correctly?
4. Do I need to set special permissions?

Thanks,
Angus

Comment: Did you set the permissions to write to the SD card?

Comment: My device doesn't have an SD card. I'm using a Samsung Galaxy Nexus.

Comment: Regardless you still have grant the WRITE_EXTERNAL permission before your application can access the external storage.

Comment: Hmm I did, do that. It hasn't made a difference.